# A question based on LCM.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, least-common-multiple

A book store with name, ‘ALL BOOK STORE’ is flashed using neon lights. The words are individually flashed at the intervals of 5/2 s, 17/4 s and 41/8 s respectively and each word is **put off after a second**. The least time after which the full name of the book store can be read again is?

---

Here the answer is LCM (5/2 + 1, 17/4 + 1, 41/8 +1). In this answer we are considering only the cases when all the 3 words **start** flashing up at the same time right ?

My doubt is we can also have cases where the start times of 3 words flashing are not equal but all the 3 words (full name) is lit up right ?
Example of interval (1/2 , 3/2) (1/4,5/4) (3/4, 7/4). Here even though starting times are different but during the common time interval (3/4,5/4), all the words are lit up . Why are we not considering this case ?

Comment: Do the words start all off or on?

Comment: You can assume initially all are off or initially they are on and find the next time interval when all are on.